# Transformables with fling?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-gesture

I am trying to implement a composable which allows the user to drag and zoom an image. It seems that the most natural way to implement this is by using the `pointerInput` or `transformable` modifiers. However, both do not seem to support fling. If I try it with `scrollable` instead, then fling works but one can only drag in one orientation at the same time (even if I add `scrollable` with both orientations).

I think my use case it not completely uncommon (see e.g. MapView, which needs something similar), so I am a bit confused why Jetpack Compose does not support it properly. Am I missing something?

Comment: Fling? Do you mean pan?

Comment: By fling I mean that if you pan with force and then lift the finger, the panning should continue, gradually slowing down. This is the standard behavior of scrollable views like lists.

Comment: Oh, I don't think it's called fling exactly, but yes, this can be achieved by `decay` animation.

Comment: Ahh thanks, I wasn't aware of `animateDecay`. It even says in the docs that this can be used to implement fling behavior! (Still, I wasn't able to find this by searching "fling animation"...) I'll figure out how to implement this in my use case later and post an answer here.

Comment: By searching for `animateDecay` I found that my question is actually answered in the docs (not in the gestures tab, but in the animation tab). Now I feel a bit stupid... Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 1):

To track the velocity of your finger and initiate an animation when the drag is released, you can use a VelocityTracker. Here is an example code:

```
val tracker = remember { VelocityTracker() }

pointerInput(enabled, horizontalReverseScrolling, verticalReverseScrolling) {
    do {
        val event = awaitPointerEvent()
        val canceled = event.changes.fastAny { it.isConsumed }

        if (!pastTouchSlop) {
                zoom *= zoomChange
                rotation += rotationChange
                pan += panChange

                val centroidSize = event.calculateCentroidSize(useCurrent = false)
                val zoomMotion = abs(1 - zoom) * centroidSize
                val rotationMotion = abs(rotation * PI.toFloat() * centroidSize / 180f)
                val panMotion = pan.getDistance()

                if (zoomMotion > touchSlop ||
                    rotationMotion > touchSlop ||
                    panMotion > touchSlop
                ) {
                    pastTouchSlop = true
                    lockedToPanZoom = panZoomLock && rotationMotion < touchSlop
                }
            }

            if (pastTouchSlop) {
                val centroid = event.calculateCentroid(useCurrent = false)
                val effectiveRotation = if (lockedToPanZoom) 0f else rotationChange
                if (effectiveRotation != 0f ||
                    zoomChange != 1f ||
                    panChange != Offset.Zero
                ) {
                    onGesture(centroid, panChange, zoomChange, effectiveRotation, dragEvent)
                    
                    
                     tracker.addPointerInputChange(change)
                }
                event.changes.fastForEach {
                    if (it.positionChanged()) {
                        it.consume()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } while (!canceled && event.changes.fastAny { it.pressed })

    // Call the callback function and pass the velocity when the drag ends
    val velocity = tracker.calculateVelocity()
    tracker.resetTracking()
    onEnd(Offset(tracker.x, tracker.y))
}
```

Finally, in the callback function, start the animation using the velocity information. Here is an example of how to use rememberSplineBasedDecay and AnimationState to create the animation:

```
val flingSpec = rememberSplineBasedDecay<Offset>()
launch {
    AnimationState(
        typeConverter = Offset.VectorConverter,
        initialValue = Offset.Zero,
        initialVelocity = velocityOffset,
    ).animateDecay(flingSpec) { animationValue ->
        val delta = animationValue - lastValue
        // Handle the offset value in the animation callback
        onGesture(offset = delta)
        lastValue = animationValue
    }
}
```